# Why is my screen session terminating in the middle of a server startup?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

Some background first, I am running Ubuntu 64-bit server on a machine running ESXi. I have just installed this VM today specifically for this task. This task is to run a tModLoader server with as little outside interference as possible.

I set up firewalld with a service for terraria that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<service>
  <short>Terraria</short>
  <description>Open TCP port 7777 for incoming Terraria client connections.</description>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="7777"/>
</service>
```

I set up UFW to allow only ssh and port 7777/tcp.

I added a rule for iptables with this command:
`sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 7777 -j ACCEPT`

I created a user called "terraria" with options -r -m -d

I set up the server files in `/opt/terraria` with the exception of the ModLoader files which are installed in two locations because they are dependent on the user that starts the process. The location of those are `~/.local/share/Terraria/ModLoader`

I created a service for terraria in `/etc/systemd/system/terraria.service` that looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=server daemon for terraria

[Service]
Type=forking
User=terraria
KillMode=none
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -dmS terraria /bin/bash -c "/opt/terraria/tModLoaderServer -config /opt/terraria/serverconfig.txt"
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/terrariad exit

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I made a script that allows me to easily access the screen session the service starts in:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

send="`printf \"$*\r\"`"
attach='script /dev/null -qc "screen -r terraria"'
inject="screen -S terraria -X stuff $send"

if [ "$1" = "attach" ] ; then cmd="$attach" ; else cmd="$inject" ; fi

if [ "`stat -c '%u' /var/run/screen/S-terraria/`" = "$UID" ]
then
    $cmd
else
    su - terraria -c "$cmd"
fi
```

With all of that out of the way, the issue I am running into is that the service starts, and I can attach to the screen session while the service is running, however the screen session terminates after a few seconds while the server is starting up. I have no idea why that happens. Starting the server as my own user seems to work properly, but I need it to be able to run as a service with a system user so that the server will automatically run upon boot.

As a side note the config file doesn't work oddly.

Any ideas and help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Screen terminates after the inner script completes. You could prevent this by running something after your script that doesn't end, for example `bash -c`

Comment: The issue is that the inner script is not completing. It just terminates while the script is running, the script shouldn't be closing where the screen terminates.